# Opening a Neptune Notebook on a different browser (not the default one)

Tags: authentication, julia, chromium

OK, so I've gotten acquainted with Neptune notebooks (a fork of Pluto notebooks) and they work fine on my machine, even on the FF browser (my default browser right now).

However, as the printing capabilities of these notebooks aren't quite there yet, I need to open a notebook on Chrome (or its open-source version, Chromium). When I try to do that, I get an authentication error (something about a "secret" that it needs, though it's quite vague as to what that is and where it would be inputted on the browser). I have full access privileges to all the folders involved, on my Linux Mint machine, running one of the latest versions of Julia.

Is there a way to do that, without having to make that my default browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use the option `launch_browser=false` when starting Neptune.

```
julia> Neptune.run(;launch_browser=false)

Go to http://localhost:1234/?secret=xs5m1mnx in your browser to start writing ~ have fun!

Press Ctrl+C in this terminal to stop Neptune
```

Now copy the link that you see in console (`http://localhost:1234/?secret=xs5m1mnx` in my case) to Chromium and have fun!